# gcd of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

For two integer a and b, if the (a, b)=c, then it must exist x and y such that ax+by=c.(The converse is not always true). But for two polynomials $f(x)$ and $p(x)$, if they can be written as $a(x)p(x)+b(x)f(x)=1$, can I conclude that the gcd of them is 1?

-If it is not true, how could I keep proving their gcd is 1 after I get $a(x)p(x)+b(x)f(x)=1$

For example, if $a, b \in F$ and $a \neq b$, to show that a+x and b+x is relatively prime in $F[x]$

For my understand, I got $(a-b)^-(a+x)-(a-b)^-(b+x)=1$, so the linear combination of these two polynomials can be 1, but is it enough to say that the gcd of them is 1?

Comment: What is $(a-b)^-$ ?  Do you mean $(a-b)^{-1}$?

Comment: $d\mid p,f\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid ap+bf = 1,\,$ i.e. $\,d\mid 1,\,$ ie. $\,cd = 1,\,$ so the gcd $= 1$, since we normalize polynomial gcds to be *monic* (lead coef $= 1)$

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a gcd of $p$ and $f$, then $p$ and $f$ can both be written as multiples of $g$. It follows that any linear combination $ap + bf$ can be written as a multiple of $g$. Thus if $1$ is a linear combination of $p$ and $f$, then $1$ is a multiple of $g$, meaning $g$ is a unit and $p, f$ are coprime.

In general, since $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain (assuming $F$ means a field), we can write $(p, f) = (g)$ for some $g \in F[x]$. (Here $(q_1, q_2, \dotsc)$ means the ideal generated by $q_1, q_2, \dotsc \in F[x]$.) Then we must have that $g$ is a divisor of both $p$ and $f$, and if $g'$ is any other common divisor, $(p, f) = (g) \subseteq (g')$ implies that $g$ is a multiple of $g'$. Thus $g$ is a gcd of $p$ and $f$, and we have shown that $\gcd(p,f)$ is a linear combination of $p$ and $f$.